# react-bootstrap Jumbotron background image

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-bootstrap

Looking for a way to change the background-image of a jumbotron component

this is what I've tried but no luck:

```
class Jumbo extends Component {
  render() {
    var styles ={
      "background-image":"http://worldkings.org/Userfiles/Upload/images/Yale.jpg"
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Jumbotron style={styles}>
            <h1>Public Art</h1>
            <br/>
            <p>
            A crowd-sourced archive of art in public spaces.
            </p>

            <Button bsStyle="primary" href="#" >Learn more</Button>

            <Button bsStyle="primary" href="#" >Submit a Piece</Button> 
            {/*link these!*/}

        </Jumbotron>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

any pointers?

Comment: You probably want to try wrapping that img url in your css with `url()`

Comment: tried both
`"background-image": "url(https://images.pexels.com...)",` 
and `"background-image": "url(\"https://images.pexels.com...\")",`
but still nothing

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have to use `backgroundImage` instead of `"background-image"` for inline styles according to React doc's example:

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

Taken From: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

> **style**
>
> The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased
>   properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM
>   style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS
>   security holes.

Answer (score 1):

Found a great solution [here](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1130#issuecomment-488727142). I know this is old but it's the first result that comes up when searching the problem. Future react bootstrappers, enjoy!

> First, import your image normally:
>
> ```
> import bgimage from '../image_background.png'
> ```
>
> Then you can apply the style to your tag like so:
>
> ```
> <Jumbotron style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bgimage})`, backgroundSize: 'cover' }}>
> ```